# gatsby build failing on netlify with throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby, package.json, netlify

This error did not happen on my build from several months ago, I was on node `v14.4.0` which was using `npm v6.14.5`.

```
6:09:13 PM: $ gatsby build
6:09:13 PM: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085
6:09:13 PM:       throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
6:09:13 PM:       ^
6:09:13 PM: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/dot-prop/index.js
6:09:13 PM: require() of ES modules is not supported.
6:09:13 PM: require() of /opt/build/repo/node_modules/dot-prop/index.js from /opt/build/repo/node_modules/configstore/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
6:09:13 PM: Instead rename /opt/build/repo/node_modules/dot-prop/index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /opt/build/repo/node_modules/dot-prop/package.json.
6:09:13 PM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:13)
6:09:13 PM:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
6:09:13 PM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
6:09:13 PM:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
6:09:13 PM:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
6:09:13 PM:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:8:17)
6:09:13 PM:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
6:09:13 PM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
6:09:13 PM:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
6:09:13 PM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14) {
6:09:13 PM:   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
6:09:13 PM: }
```

[Here is the log output for the last build that worked](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/ed26dd03352adbe3ace2fb593fd79e278410bd88/working%2520build)

[Here is the log output for the build 1 after the working build](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/eb53068d7bc6201f84627f3445201934478502e2/build%25201%2520after%2520working%2520build). Nothing was updated except for a new image, and a few strings. This build failed.

Both of the above builds had the node version set to `v14.4.0`

[Here is my most recent breaking Netlify log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/20e8f2f8a68a1ee3eb897a5fec43d2b54a24427a/netlify%2520log)

It happens when [this is my package-lock.json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/71fa254de3da31ea2addf1585b239383b689e340/breaking%2520package-lock.json)

but does not happen when [this is my package-lock.json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/71fa254de3da31ea2addf1585b239383b689e340/working%2520package-lock.json)

Even with the working `package-lock.json` I must use node `v14.17.0` and npm `v7.20.5` or else I get the same error

---

With the working package-lock.json and working node and npm version, I receive [this new error](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/20e8f2f8a68a1ee3eb897a5fec43d2b54a24427a/New%2520error%2520with%2520the%2520non-breaking%2520package-lock.json)

```
6:49:50 PM: success Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 144.047s - 675/675 4.69/s
6:49:50 PM: error UNHANDLED EXCEPTION write EPIPE
6:49:50 PM: 
6:49:50 PM: 
6:49:50 PM:   Error: write EPIPE
6:49:50 PM:   
6:49:50 PM:   - child_process.js:839 ChildProcess.target._send
6:49:50 PM:     internal/child_process.js:839:20
6:49:50 PM:   
6:49:50 PM:   - child_process.js:710 ChildProcess.target.send
6:49:50 PM:     internal/child_process.js:710:19
6:49:50 PM:   
6:49:50 PM:   - index.js:298 WorkerPool.sendMessage
6:49:50 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby-worker]/dist/index.js:298:19
6:49:50 PM:   
6:49:50 PM:   - worker-messaging.ts:22 
6:49:50 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby]/src/utils/jobs/worker-messaging.ts:22:22
```

---

This is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "suddenly-saskatchewan-magazine-website",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Suddenly Saskachewan Magazine Website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Sam Germain",
  "keywords": [
    "suddenly saskatchewan",
    "saskatchewan"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build --log-pages",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing \"",
    "type-check": "tsc -w"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/samgermain/sudSaskV2.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/samgermain/sudSaskV2/issues"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "dot-prop": ">=5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
    "@pittica/gatsby-plugin-recaptcha": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby": "^4.11.3",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.6.0",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^4.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-graphql-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.11.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^6.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preconnect": "^1.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^6.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-root-import": "^2.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.11.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.11.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.11.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^4.11.1",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.11.1",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2": "^0.1.5",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.11.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.11.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.11.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "jshint": "^2.13.4",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "preact": "^10.7.1",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.21",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0"
  }
}
```

[This was my package.json for the last build that worked](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samgermain/3df18bf3c709406df1b3769dd705fd61/raw/f1a65fe3948aae151970d792e1670f6ac5b871cb/package.json%2520for%2520the%2520last%2520working%2520build)

---

I am getting the same build error when building on gatsby cloud

---

My site is still using `gatsby-image` instead of `gatsby-plugin-image`, I have a branch that I have spent a few hours on trying to switch `gatsby-image` to `gatsby-plugin-image`, but it still has problems, so I do not know if this update will fix this issue

---

## UPDATE

One random build on netlify worked

Comment: Why use `resolutions` with `npm` which supports `overrides` instead?

Comment: Your example of a non working package-lock.json is incomplete, and your example for a working package-lock.json is empty. You haven't stated what versions of node and npm you would prefer to use either.

The gist of your issue is you must have been getting a version of `dot-prop` installed that was requiring imports of ES Modules. I would change the `resolutions` field name to `overrides` and try to `npm install` again from a working packge-lock.json.

Comment: @morganney `. I would change the resolutions field name to overrides` what do you mean exactly? and I don't have a preference for any node or npm version

Comment: @morganney Thanks, I uploaded the files, apparently when you update a gist twice within a small timeframe, the first updates are discarded

Answer (score 2):

> error UNHANDLED EXCEPTION write EPIPE

This error is generally related to a timeout response from the server and, depending on some build parameters it may fail or not, that's the reason why it wasn't happening before.

The timeout can appear for multiple reasons (new packages, loss of cache files, hard image processing, etc). In your case, I think it's related to the image processing process. Try removing `AVIF` (which is CPU-intensive) if you are using it and use the default formats (`WEBP` and `auto`).

In the case of the `gatsby-plugin-image` branch try setting the default options:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      options: {
        defaults: {
          formats: [`auto`, `webp`],
          placeholder: `dominantColor`,
          quality: 50,
          breakpoints: [750, 1080, 1366, 1920],
          backgroundColor: `transparent`,
          tracedSVGOptions: {},
          blurredOptions: {},
          jpgOptions: {},
          pngOptions: {},
          webpOptions: {},
          avifOptions: {},
        }
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
  ],
}
```

In the case of `gatsby-image`, try using the [specific query fragments `withWebp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-image/#image-query-fragments).

Another alternative to bypass this CPU-intense work on Netlify's side is using the CDN that Netlify provides to use along with Gatsby images, this will save a lot of time-consuming processes during the building. More details at:

- https://www.netlify.com/blog/gatsby-image-cdn-on-netlify
- https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-gatsby/blob/main/docs/image-cdn.md

If the issue persists, another known working solution is to rollback Gatsby from `^4.11.3` to `4.7.2`, locking the version if needed.

A more detailed explanation of the solutions described can be found at:

- https://answers.netlify.com/t/error-unhandled-exception-write-epipe/52650
- https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-gatsby/issues/259

---

As per the `dot-drop` error, the cause is that in your `node_modules` or in your code, your dependencies are using both `type=module` and and without `type=module` (https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868#issuecomment-586705453). This is caused normally by an upgrade of dependencies or a change of Node version.

Try setting the bundler in the `netlify.toml` file:

```
[functions]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
```

*Source: https://answers.netlify.com/t/getting-must-use-import-to-load-es-module-when-using-node-fetch-in-netlify-functions/47230*

Alternatively, add the following line in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

This essentially enables ES6 modules.

More details can be found at: [Why is 'type: module' in package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401475/why-is-type-module-in-package-json-file)

Comment: Will switching to gatsby-plugin-image probably solve my issue? I spent a few hours on a branch doing that, but gave up on it because I wasn't even sure if it would fix my issue

Comment: Unless I use that specific `package-lock.json`, I get the `dot-prop` error, do you know how I can disect that and lock certain packages to not be updated?

Comment: Regarding the use of `gatsby-image-plugin` I'm not sure if it will help. My bet is on timeout on image treatment but I can't be sure without seeing it. It will certainly help but I think it's a matter of picking the proper version. You should remove the `package-lock.json` and remove the caret in the `package.json`. passing from `^4.11.3` to `4.7.2`. Because it's a minor downgrade you should be able to do it.

Comment: I need the package-lock.json, or else the build fails. Removing all the excess extra images I had worked for fixing the EPIPE issue, I'm going to leave this question open until the bounty expires, to see if anyone else has a solution to the `dot-prop` issue. This answer will get it if there's no other answers because it's been the most helpful so far.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly. I meant to remove the `package-lock.json`, locking the version in the `package.json` and generating it again with `npm install`. As you said it's needed, indeed.

Comment: Using `"gatsby": "4.7.2"` didn't fix the `dot-prop` issue, even with the `package-lock.json` regenerated. Regenerating the package-lock.json creates the issue

Comment: I didn't try using the gatsby cloud cdn, but I did try building on gatsby cloud, and then hosting on netlify, but gatsby cloud would get the dot-prop error. Only the one random build worked, and now they're all failing.

Comment: Check the updated answer for the `dot-drop` issue. Adding the new configuration in the `netlify.toml` or the `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Your `write EPIPE` error is a timeout happening to gatsby v4 builds in Netlify and a workaround is to set `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD` environment variable to `16` (or less) as said [in this forum](https://answers.netlify.com/t/gatsby-v4-works-locally-but-timed-out-on-netlify/46339/28?u=massick)

That should avoid that you reach Netlify memory limit

Comment: Where can you set the `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD` environment variable?

Comment: I added a `.env` file with `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=16` to my project directory, and the `EPIPE` error is still there. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I just added it on [netlify "build and deploy" > "environment_variables"](https://i.imgur.com/AFQekGb.png) as well, and also receive the `EPIPE` error

Comment: I had to set GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=8 in my portfolio and it is an small site. Hope you solve it